# I want to enable ScrollView in TextView.When TextView Height Is Increased

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview

1)I want to enable ScrollView in TextView.When TextView Height Is Increased.

2) when I am Entering full lines after pressing enter what I am typing is showing.But when I am entering just 2 or 3 letters after pressing enter what I am entering is not showing.It is showing after pressing enter

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
{
  UITextView *txtView=[[UITextView alloc]init];
  txtView.frame = CGRectMake(60, 100, 350, 154);
  txtView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
  txtView.font=[UIFont fontWithName:Nil size:30];/*Font size*/
  txtView.delegate=self;
  txtView.scrollEnabled=YES;
  [self.view addSubview:txtView];
 }
 -(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
 { 
 if(textView.contentSize.height>textView.frame.size.height)
 {
 CGRect frame = txtView.frame;
 frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height+90;
 textView.frame = frame;
 textView.scrollEnabled=YES;
 }
 textView.scrollEnabled=YES;
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand, *why* you want to change the contentsize of the textView manually. The UITextView takes care of all the things on it's own, including the contentsize, and scrolling. Unless you want to set the contentsize to something more than the height of the content it actually has, you should not set the contentsize or scrollEnabled.

Comment: Also, what you have done her is, change the height of the textView frame. If you want to have a TextView that changes height accoring to it's content, have a look at [HPGrowingTextView](https://github.com/yatinsns/HPGrowingTextView)

Comment: txtView=[[UITextView alloc]init];
    txtView.frame = CGRectMake(60, 100, 350, 154);
    txtView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    txtView.font=[UIFont fontWithName:Nil size:30];

Comment: My problem is when I am entering text in TextView after reaching fourth line ending if I am pressing enter and typing text It is not showing what I am entering.After pressing enter the text is showing.If I am not pressing enter after reaching fourth line ending It is automatically going to next line and it is showing what I am entering.In this case no problem.

Comment: Are there views right above/below your textView, as in up and down. ?

Comment: Sorry! I did not get what you are asking.

Comment: Does the frame of your textView intersect with any other frame ?

Comment: No,please run this code .then you can understand.              txtView=[[UITextView alloc]init]; txtView.frame = CGRectMake(60, 100, 350, 154); txtView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor]; txtView.font=[UIFont fontWithName:Nil size:30];

Comment: Firstly, set the UIFont properly. Setting the size to 30 has no effect if you assign Nil as Font. It will just take the default system font and size. I'm implementing textViewDIdChange now.

Comment: So all in all, your problem is that your textView doesnot scroll ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(textView.contentSize.height > textView.frame.size.height)
{
    CGRect frame = textView.frame;
    frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height + 90;
    textView.frame = frame;
    textView.scrollEnabled = YES;

    [textView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0, textView.frame.size.height + 1)];
}
```

Comment: If I am tried like this scrollView is disabling in textView and I do not want Increase the textHeight.Because below the textView I have one submit button.

Comment: Please state clearly what behaviour you want from textView.
Do you want to change the height of the frame of the textView, or only enable scroll?

Comment: I need 1 thing.1)Text should be shown when the user entering the text.For example textView height is 4 lines.when the user coming to the end of  4th line it is automatically come to the next line and it is showing what is typing.In my case I will enter only 1 letter per line after entering 4th line letter I press enter then the cursor goes to next line and what I am entering is not showing.It is showing after pressing Text

Comment: show the code of the UIButton you have created. Specifically it's frame.

Comment: I think you did not get my problem.below the textview button is there.

Comment: Please read my previous second last post. you create textview and do practically then you will get my problem

Comment: Just you create one UITextView and enter text.